# How to make a skype settings file?

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, default-settings

Is there a way to make a settings file for skype on a windows 7 (home) laptop which will 
select the default audio input device, default audio output device and always answer using video mode ? 
For context, I want to be able to simply send this file to the other party(aged and not computer experts) and ask them to double click it and have a successful video call.

Comment: Skype doesn't have a settings file it uses the registry.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is kind of beyond the reach of just Skype. You will probably need to use scripting tools or other programming, likely in .net languages such as  Visual Basic or C#.

[Simple VB Skype Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRie-jtLJ0w)

Comment: The Skype desktop API doesn't have any methods for settings such as audio devices, etc.